# change one line of different files differently in bash

Tags: shell-script

I want to generate 5 files and write the same thing except one line needs to have a different number

```
for i in {1..5}
do
cat >File-$i<<!
   Line1
   Line2
   Line3
   Line4
!
done
```

In Line2 of all five files, I want to have different things written
That is for File-1  Line2 needs to be replaced by `for j in {17392..17565}`
File-2 Line2 needs to be replaced by `for j in {17566..17739}`
File-3 Line2 needs to be replaced by `for j in {17740..17913}`
And so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash

offset='17218'

for i in {1..5}
do
start=$((offset+i*174))
end=$((offset+i*174+173))
cat >File-$i<<!
   Line1
   for j in {${start}..${end}}
   Line3
   Line4
!
done
```